# Is && a qualifier?

Tags: c++

I know that `const` and `volatile` are mentioned in the C++ specification as the "cv-qualifiers", like [[basic.type.qualifier]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.type.qualifier).

Now I have this code ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/sj1Mzr35z)) which doesn't compile.

```cpp
#include <string>
class Dummy
{
    std::string member{"test"};

    public:
    std::string const && foo() &&
    { return std::move(member); }
};

int main()
{
    Dummy d;
    std::string s = d.foo();
}
```

It doesn't compile because `w` is an LValue and `foo()` only exists for RValues. That's fine and expected.

But let's have a look at the error message:

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:14:26: error: passing 'Dummy' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   14 |     std::string s = d.foo();
      |                     ~~~~~^~
<source>:7:26: note:   in call to 'const std::string&& Dummy::foo() &&'
    7 |     std::string const && foo() &&
      |
```

The error message says "discards qualifiers". Thus my question: is `&&` considered a qualifier, too? If it's not a qualifier, what is it then?

I can understand that the compiler would need to drop `&&` to `&` or to nothing in order to make it compile. So yes, it needs to discard something. But what exactly is it that it would need to drop?

Comment: With `std::string const && foo() &&`  the last `&&` says this function is only usable with rvalues.  `d` is not an rvalue so it can't call `foo`.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610571/what-is-rvalue-reference-for-this

Comment: [Member_functions_with_ref-qualifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#Member_functions_with_ref-qualifier)

Comment: @ThomasWeller Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55959119/4342498

Comment: Unrelated, but returning `std::string const &&` makes little sense. You'll have a copy of `member`, although the intention probably is to have a move.

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike: In the question I stated "It doesn't compile because w is an LValue and foo() only exists for RValues. That's fine and expected." I know that it doesn't compile and I understand why it doesn't compile. I just need it not to compile in order to get an error message. So, your first proposed link is not a dupe.

Comment: Sorry everyone for not responding in a timely manner. I was in a meeting.

Comment: @EvgsupportsModeratorStrike: yes, it doesn't make sense. That's the point I'm trying to make with my team members. I should have left that const out in the MRE though. The complete code will show where copies and moves are made and that const prevents optimization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a qualifier. The quote you refer to is about types, but the qualifier that is dropped here is that of a member function.

Not sure if there is a better quote, though it mentions the terms in context at least: [class.mfct.non.static](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.mfct.non.static#3)

> [Note 2: An implicit object member function can be declared with cv-qualifiers, which affect the type of the `this` pointer ([expr.prim.this]), and/or a ref-qualifier ([dcl.fct]); both affect overload resolution ([over.match.funcs])
> — end note]

Comment: [N2439](https://wg21.link/N2439) is the proposal that adds ref-qualifiers to the language, since C++11.

Comment: **ref-qualifier**, that's it. Maybe you want to link [dcl.fct] and [dcl.decl.general], especially https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl.general#nt:ref-qualifier