Optimal way to return value
Consider the following:
template <typename T>
struct S
{
    T Value() &&
    {
        // Option 1
        return value;
        // Option 2
        // return std::move(value);
        // Option 3
        // return T{std::move(value)};
    }

    T value;
};

I want to ensure when someone writes auto var = S<ComplexType>{}.Value() (as an example, obviously in real code it would be more complex), then value is returned through move-construction if the underlying object is move copyable, otherwise through copy-construction.
I have given 3 options in the code based on my own understanding, but it is possible the correct answer lies elsewhere. What is the best way to return by value in this case?
FURTHER EDIT: OK, my original example wasn't correct. This is the underlying problem I want to solve. If I say
template <typename T>
struct S
{
    T&& Value()&&
    {
        return std::move(value);
    }

    T value;
};

I basically allow anyone to get the internal state of my object by saying auto var = S<ComplexType>{}; std::move(var).Value().CallNonConstMethod();. It is the same as returning T&. I don't want to do that.

Related: C++11 rvalues and move semantics with return statement

return std::move(value); is what you want but you also need to change T Value() const && to T&& Value() const && related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55958970/does-it-make-sense-for-a-function-to-return-an-rvalue-reference/55959119#55959119

Remember that if you "move" the value, the variable value would still be valid but in an indeterminate state. You can no longer use value without reinitializing it.

@NathanOliver I don't want to return an rvalue reference, I want to force users to copy into a new variable. The only thing is that I want the copy to be move-construction if possible.

@Someprogrammerdude -- it's worse than that. "Valid but indeterminate state" is required for all types defined by the C++ standard; there is no guarantee that user-defined types will behave sensibly.

@Someprogrammerdude which is why the signature of this function specifies && that is it will only be invoked on temporaries.

@Honey To allow only one move you have to return by rvalue reference, otherwise you'll get 2 moves

What is the actual and underlying problem you need to solve? Why do you need to "move-copy" (which makes no sense) the value? What is the problem that is supposed to solve? Please [edit] your question to ask about that underlying and actual problem directly.

I would suggest using std::forward(), as it is not clear that T is movable.

@S.Gleissner How could std::forward help here?

The use-case you mention make it seems like a convoluted factor pattern. Why would this only be used with temporary objects? I'm sorry, but in its current state your question is abn XY problem.

@Evg it combines option 1 & 2. If the template parameter T is movable, it is moved (which is faster), else it is copied.

What you want is move then copy, which is a non-sense. It would be equivalent, in the end, to simply copy.

@S.Gleissner Please show some code. std::forward itself doesn't care whether T is movable or not, it is just static_cast<T&&>.

@Fareanor By marking the function with "&&", it is clear that it is called on a temporary object (= rvalue reference). So it is perfectly legal to move the value out of it, if possible. The return value with type T is also a temporary object (= rvalue reference).

@S.Gleissner It's not a matter of being legal or not, it's a matter of being useless ! The move is an extra-unneccessary operation here, if you want to copy anyway, it's useless to move before :) The end result would be the same except you have done extra work for nothing

@Someprogrammerdude edited the question with my reasoning.

@Fareanor Not for nothing. Imagine (generic) code like this: auto&& value = S<T>().Value();. If Value() returns an r-value reference, value will become a dangling reference. If Value() return a value, value will be a valid reference to a temporary with extended life time.

the member is public, though even if it is private, the issue is returning a non-const reference. Once you do return a non const reference the caller can do whatever they like to it. If you want encapuslation simply do not return a non const reference.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai which leads to my original question above. How do I make sure value is move-constructed out of the object where a move constructor is available, otherwise copy-constructed.

@Evg Fareanor, You are possibly right, as std::forward is normally used inside template functions with templated arguments (which is not the case here). Also Honey made clear in his latest edit, that he wants to copy, not to move.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I am trying to be optimal, so not sure if return T{std::move(value)}; is better, or return std::move(value); is better. In a statement such as auto var = s.Value(); would the simple move create a temporary first and then copy construct into var?

Doing return T{std::move(value)}; within T&& Value() && function will return a dangling reference, don't do it.

@Evg I was asking about doing it within T Value() &&

Within T Value() &&, doing return T{std::move(value)}; has no benefit over return std::move(value);.

I dont understand the problem when return type is T. And I dont udnerstand why you ask for that when the "underlying problem" is about have return type T&&

"[...] It is the same as returning T&. I don't want to do that." ok. What do you want?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I want to return T, optimally. That is, it should be move-constructed if that is supported, otherwise copy-constructed.

@Evg many thanks. So you are saying return T{std::move(value)}; wouldn't provide a copy-elision benefit over return std::move(value); ? Could you maybe write an answer and explain the technical reasons why there is no benefit?

What do you mean by a copy elision benefit in this case? Why do you think return T{std::move(value)}; could be better than return std::move(value);?

@Evg because my current understanding says that return T{std::move(value)}; in conjuction with auto v = s.Value(); would make sure that v is move-constructed from value, whereas I am not sure if that would be the case for the other option. I am looking for the right return expression, and the technical reason why it is the right return expression.

The old school would be to define 2 overloads:
T&  S::Value() const&
T&& S::Value() &&

With almost identical code. That was annoying to most; considering 12 different combos of cv+ref qualifiers, that would be a headache.
In C++23 we could do slightly better:
T&  S::Value(this S const& self);
T&& S::Value(this S &&     self);

This new syntax enables us to make this of a template argument type:
template<typename self_t>
decltype(auto) S::Value(this self_t&& self){
    return std::forward_like<self_t>(self.value);
};

Alternatively you can:
return std::forward<self_t>(self).value;

With similar effect. You can also use the shorthand template version:
decltype(auto) S::Value(this auto&& self);

This last syntax has been the inspiration to call the feature deducing this. For template meta programming reasons, library developers prefer to avoid deduced return types; if you need to be explicit about return type then trailing return type could be simpler to write:
template<typename self_t> 
auto S::Value(this self_t&& self)
     ->decltype(std::forward<self_t>(self).value;

But if you want to avoid repetition, you'll need to create some boilerplate library for such return types.

But I don't want to return T&&. I want to return T.

That's easier. Why do you think you cannot? Just specify the return type as T.
