If a C++ function returns some heavy object by value should I capture it by const ref or by value?
I always thought that the right thing to do when capturing some heavy object returned by value from a function is to do it by const reference to avoid additional copy from the temporary to the target variable. This way extends the temporary's lifetime as described by this article by Herb Sutter. Now I played with Godbolt to compare the code generated both ways and surprisingly for me the code that captures the returned temporary by value looks shorter. I know about RVO and NRVO optimizations but I tested the code in -O0 optimization level. Are those optimizations performed even on -O0 and is still there a case when capturing the returned value by const reference is preferable?
Here is the C++ code:
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string foo() {
    return "test";
}

void bar() {
    auto y = foo();
}

void dar() {
    const auto& z = foo();
}

Here is the generated by GCC 14.2, x86-64 assembly for the bar and dar functions:
bar():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 32
        lea     rax, [rbp-32]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    foo[abi:cxx11]()
        lea     rax, [rbp-32]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() [complete object destructor]
        leave
        ret
dar():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 48
        lea     rax, [rbp-48]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    foo[abi:cxx11]()
        lea     rax, [rbp-48]
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax
        lea     rax, [rbp-48]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string() [complete object destructor]
        leave
        ret

The generated assembly for the dar function that captures the returned value by const reference is two instructions longer:
lea     rax, [rbp-48]
mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax

Here is the link to the code in Godbolt.

"when capturing some heavy object..." I would recommend not using the word "capturing" here as it has a separate meaning.

Is there a particular need you have for -O0? It is typically meaningless to look at performance in -O0.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision : from C++17 some copy elision are mandatory (whatever the optimization level, which is not a thing in the standard)

Which C++ version are you using. This article is from 2008, and now C++20 is supported on most platform, so there will be no copy in x = foo();

@Oersted OP seems to be already aware of it.

"s still there a case when capturing the returned value by const reference is preferable?..." Yes, when you don't want the object to be modifiable, use the const ref.

@François Andrieux I changed it to C++20, and I tagged the question to C++20. But there is no difference in the assembly for this example.

@user12002570 WIth the same effect I can use const value without ref.

@François Andrieux Sometimes the performance of the debug builds is also important.

const auto& z = foo(); is special case called "lifetime extension".

@bobeff Yes, from c++17 all of the three are the same. The version with const just won't let you modify the objects.

C++ has Mandatory return value optimization so just return by value.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10194011/1387438

@MarekR An understanding of lifetime extension is already shown in the question. The question is asking about the difference in assembly generated by using a lifetime extending reference vs a traditional local object.

With -O2 or -O1 there is none: https://godbolt.org/z/qe96sc4dW and there is no point to care about -O0.

If you use value semantics, from C++17 onward you're guaranteed to get direct initialization, which is in effect similar to using a reference along with life extension. But the value semantics has clearer meaning and less probablity of causing errors. It can also be useful in triggering NRVO, if the object is supposed to be returned.


I know about RVO and NRVO optimizations but I tested the code in -O0 optimization level. Are those optimizations performed even on -O0

Yes, some copy elision is mandatory in modern C++ but that is not actually what makes a difference here.
Your dar function captures by const-ref but the compiler still has to extend the lifetime of the object returned by value. As far as the compiler is concerned, the dar function has to work like this:
auto __anonymous_hidden_object = foo();
const auto& z = __anonymous_hidden_object;

This is what you see in the assembly. The extra code is for the creation of that reference.

it allocates more stack space to store the reference on the stack (it adds 16 byte instead of 8 due to stack alignment)
After the construction, it stores the reference on the stack (mov QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax)
Then it does a superfluous reload (lea rax, [rbp-48]) for no other reason than that it's a -O0 build and the compiler is not expected to be smart

If you compile with any sort of optimization, the difference will go away because the compiler knows that it can treat a reference to a local variable the same as the variable itself.
In general, most programming advise will not cater to -O0 builds. The generated assembly is too different and generally of no interest for the final result. Even for a debug build I advise you to use -O1, otherwise you may not even see the same bugs that you are trying to debug. See for example Program only crashes as release build -- how to debug? Plus, who wants to sieve through huge assemblies full of register reloads anyway?
-O0 is not intended for debugging either and I don't know why IDEs and build systems still insist on making it the default for debug builds. Its purpose is to minimize compile time. Good for things like configure scripts that test if code compiles to see if compiler features or certain headers are available; or for code that only runs once. GCC has an optimization level specifically for debugging, -Og

Optimize debugging experience. -Og should be the optimization level of choice for the standard edit-compile-debug cycle, offering a reasonable level of optimization while maintaining fast compilation and a good debugging experience. It is a better choice than -O0 for producing debuggable code because some compiler passes that collect debug information are disabled at -O0.

When you apply that optimization level, there will be no difference between your bar and dar functions.
